# Unable to access some websites on Amazon service

Tags: linux, curl, web-crawler, block, wget

**Description**

I'm crawling the website :[bjx.com](http://guangfu.bjx.com.cn/xtgc/List.aspx?classid=583) and all codes can be run in the local.Then I put the code on the Amazon service and run ,it failed.

**What I have Done**

I guess that maybe the website  block the server and I have tried some ways :

1) `curl http://guangfu.bjx.com.cn/xtgc/List.aspx?classid=583`

2) `wget http://guangfu.bjx.com.cn/xtgc/List.aspx?classid=583`

**err msg as follows:**

```
Resolving news.bjx.com.cn (news.bjx.com.cn)... 114.113.145.103
Connecting to news.bjx.com.cn (news.bjx.com.cn)|114.113.145.103|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2019-04-23 05:45:00--  (try: 2)  http://news.bjx.com.cn/list
Connecting to news.bjx.com.cn (news.bjx.com.cn)|114.113.145.103|:80...
```

**some reference:**

https://serverfault.com/questions/124952/testing-a-website-from-linux-command-line

**My question :**

how to confirm whether the website has blocked me and if blocked, what can I do to solve the issue and crawl the website, thanks

Comment: They might be rate-limiting you.

Comment: @Barmar so can you help me to confirm the rate-limiting issue ? just call one time ?thanks

Comment: If you just called one time then it's obviously not rate limiting.

Comment: I tried your `curl` command and I get `403 Forbidden` response.

Comment: I was able to get around that by sending a Chrome user agent. But if you're getting a connection timeout, they're blocking you at the network level, so that won't solve it.

Comment: @Barmar Actually, I also can get around the website in the local.but I can't run it in the server

Comment: Sounds like the website is blocking your server.

Answer (score 0):

How about to make the program failed with particular timeout setting?

For example, to make curl failed if it can't get response within 10 seconds

> curl -m 10

And, to go over these issues, you can try to run the spiders with Proxy of VPN networking

Comment: thank you in advance. I have tried the command 'curl -m 10'  but failed. and I use the Amazon china server so I think it is not related with VPN

Comment: Even you're using Amazon China, the target site still has ability to block you according to your IP, http headers or even user-agent.

You'll need to find a way to make the spider running machine has ability to access the target URL, a Proxy or VPN which has ability to access the target site would be a way.

The VPN here is nothing to do with the "VPN" which generally understood used to span GFW.